# Add dynamic JSON LD to a script tag in Vue 3 using v-html

Tags: vuejs3, json-ld

I have a function that returns dynamically generated JSON-LD as a string. I want to embed it in a script tag in my template.

This works:

`<component :innerHTML="myJsonLdFunction(mySearchResult) :is="'script'" type="application/ld+json"></component>`

But this does not work - the script tag stays empty:

`<component v-html="myJsonLdFunction(mySearchResult)" :is="'script'" type="application/ld+json"></component>`

What's the explanation for this difference? According to the documentation, `v-html` will "update the element's innerHTML". So it should work as well, right?